# How to determine Leading coefficient in polynomial functions

Tags: functions, exponential-function

In the polynomial function, V(x) = (5-x)(3-x)(4-x), why is the leading coefficient considered -1, instead of 1? Since each x in the factor have an exponent of 1, shouldn't the leading exponent also be 1?

Comment: Consider $(-x)(-x)(-x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The leading coefficient of a polynomial is the coefficient of the highest degree term. Here $V(x) = (5-x)(3-x)(4-x) = (15 -8x +x^2)(4-x) = 60 - ax -bx^2 -x^3$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Thus the leading coefficient of $V$ is $-1$.

Comment: So is the value of -1 in lead coefficient from -1 in -1x^3?